# Running the program with logical threads

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, multicore

I have a multi-core which hyper-threading is enabled.
Each physical core has two logical core. Now can i run my program with 1 core and its logical cores? means our program run with 2 logical core's of this one core but other cores are idle.

Comment: From the applications point of view, a logical core is just a core and a thread is a thread. And how the threads will be allocated to cores is up to the operating system. If you wat a thread to be on a speciic core, you have to [set its affinity](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Now can i run my program with 1 core and its logical cores?

Yes, but to utilize more cores than 1 you must execute your app in multiple threads. Ie. if you are using pthreads then use `pthread_setaffinity_np` to specify on which core your thread should execute.

If you want to make your agorithms run in parallel then consider using OpenMP or TBB (Threading Building Blocks). Those libraries allow to quite easily convert sequentially executed application into parallel one. Ie. instead of using `for` you use `parallel_for`. Also your code will automatically use all available (or cofigured) number of cores - whether CPU has 2 cores or 16 of them.

Comment: You may also find this talk on scalable parallelisation by Ulrich Drepper of value: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfimI7UC9Pg